# Seems like subprocess.Popen is not releasing the lock

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to execute a batch script through python and seems like subprocess.Popen is executing the command and it's getting stuck there on terminal and not printing any output though copy completed.  Can you help on this.

```
ps_copy_command = "call copyfiles.cmd"
process=subprocess.Popen(["cmd", "/C", ps_copy_command, password], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE);
    process.wait()
    print("\tCopy completed ")
    output = process.stdout.read()
    print (output)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using subprocess.run to address this.

```
process=subprocess.run(["cmd", "/C", ps_copy_command, password], stdout=subprocess.PIPE);
    print(process.returncode)
    print(process.stdout)
```

Answer (score 1):

If the code is stuked in `output = process.stdout.read()`, something similar happened to me some time ago. The problem is that process.stdout.read() wont return something until stdout has something in it. Example:

Imagine your batch script is doing some task that takes 10 seconds and then print 'Done!'

python is going to wait until 'Done!' returned by the script.

They way i solved this problems is by adding Threads. One thread is reading the stdout and the other is waiting n seconds, then i join the waiting thread and if the stdout thread has something in it, i print it

```
import time
import threading

def wait_thread():
    seconds = 0
    while seconds < 2:
        time.sleep(1)
        seconds += 1
    return True

def stdout_thread():
    global output
    output = process.stdout.read()


output=None
t1 = threading.Thread(target=wait_thread)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=stdout_thread)

t1.start()
t2.start()

t1.join()     # wait until waiting_thread is end  

if output:
    print(output)
else:
    print("No output")
```

Comment: Thanks Sergio. But, my batch script returns somewhat significant output(at least 100 lines). so, stdout must have something in it. And, you have mentioned that python is going to wait until script completes. That should be OK. But, problem is copy completed and nothing happening after that. I am also checking your approach.

Comment: Maybe you should replace `process.wait() ` with: `(stdout_data, stderr_data) = process.comunicate()`. comunicate takes 2 arguments, the first the data to send in stdin (optional) and the second the timeout in seconds, it returns stdout and stderr